# Convert a time with character format to Date format

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

I have problem with a character in form: 01JAN2018:00:00:00
I want to get 2018_01_01 as result.

I tried this code but that returns NA

as.POSIXct("01JAN2018:00:00:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y")

thank you

Comment: there is no `-` in the string.  You need `as.POSIXct("01JAN2018:00:00:00", format = "%d%b%Y")`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work for me, it returns NA. is there a problem with as.POSIXct?

Comment: @DDchen ensure you are using `%b` and not `%m`

Comment: @Chabo yes, i tried exactly what akrun suggested, that's weird

Comment: using lubridate you can just use `dmy_hms('01JAN2018:00:00:00')` ... or if you want to just convert it to a date (and not a datetime object), you can do `as_date(dmy_hms('01JAN2018:00:00:00'))`

Comment: thank you all, i tried many suggestions and I tried to set the local time with: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","C") and then thats works with as.POSIXct.